# Mapping Vision Outputs To Neural Network Inputs

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, neural-network, time-series, simulink

I'm fairly new to MATLAB, but have acquainted myself with Simulink and Computer Vision over the past few days. My problem statement involves taking a traffic/highway video input and detecting if an accident has occurred.

I plan to do this by extracting the values of centroid to plot trajectory, velocity difference (between frames) and distance between two vehicles. I can successfully track the centroids, and aim to derive the rest of the features.

What I don't know is how to map these to ANN. I mean, every image has more than one vehicle blobs, which means, there are multiple centroids in a single frame/image. So, how does NN act on multiple inputs (the extracted features per vehicle) simultaneously? I am obviously missing the link. Help me figure it out please.

Also, am I looking at time series data?

Comment: Can you please describe precisely what the inputs are? Like what is a vehicle blob? Is it, vehicle ID, x, y, speed, direction, size, etc? And do you intend to feed the neural network several time-steps back in time of data?

Comment: I'm not sure you need a ANN for this; ANN would be good if, say, you have to tell if one blob is a car or not... That said, you could use datas over time, speed of cars etc., and make time series data analysis, you then will look for particular events (peak...) in the times series. They can be multidimensional, so you can gather multiple informations (speed, distance between cars...) and thus make better guesses. Be careful working with time series, you will have to reduce the dimensionality (PCA...) once this is done, maybe ANN would be a good fit. SVM is good too for time series.

Comment: The idea is to detect event, by looking at the variance ie Variance at each time step. Hence, Centroid 2 - Centroid 1, Velocity 2- Velocity 1 etc are to fed as inputs. So, the inputs are ideally to be the variance between each time step. Is it possible to carry that out with more than one vehicles per frame? Because then I have to check for variance in all the vehicles. Let's say I have 3 cars in a single frame, and 4 features per car, so that's 4 + 4 + 4 features to be tracked across time. How do we do that?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, PCA requires the whole matrix of values to work upon, right? Wouldn't that invalidate the whole purpose of being real-time?

Comment: Just use all the differences between time-steps for each variable, for as many timesteps as you're interested in, and make those the inputs to your ANN.

Comment: Yes, but how do you do that in MATLAB? Supply the variances at each time-step?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about your question. The problem can be both time series data and not. You might be able to transform the time series version of the problem, such that it can be solved using ANN, but it is sort of a Maslow's hammer :). Also, Could you rephrase the problem.

As you said, you could give it features from two or three frames and then use the classifier to detect accident or not, but it might be difficult to train such a classifier. The problem is really difficult and the so you might need tons of training samples to get it right, esp really good negative samples (for examples cars travelling close to each other) etc.

There are multiple ways you can try to solve this problem of accident detection. For example : Build a classifier (ANN/SVM etc) to detect accidents without time series data. In which case your input would be accident images and non accident images or some sort of positive and negative samples for training and later images for test. In this specific case, you are not looking at the time series data. But here you might need lots of features to detect the same (this in some sense a single frame version of the problem).

The second method would be to use time series data, in which case you will have to detect the features, track the features (say using Lucas Kanade/Horn and Schunck) and then use the information about velocity and centroid to detect the accident. You might even be able to formulate it for HMMs.

Comment: Ok, let's try an analogy.  My purpose is similar to Crab classification. Crab classification requires detection of a crab's sex by analyzing the image.  Six physical characterstics of a crab are considered: species, length, width and depth etc and fed to the NN to determine the result. My doubt stands, that what if I have two crabs in a single image? Or in my case, two cars in the same screenshot/frame of the video. How do I supply multiple sets of features to NN/frame?

Comment: I see. This is actually sort of a chicken and egg problem. But usually what is done is  this. You have a detector and recognition engine. The detector detects for cars, or crabs etc and the recognition engine classifies its sex or type of car. So you would need to initially get a detector (either using a classifier, to classify "crab" or "not crab", or some ad-hoc method). You can also use other information to make the detection really easy, for example, if I know that the car will appear first on the top left corner, I can put a detector on the top-left corner alone.